# Import .fbx animation from Maya 2012 to Unity 2018

Tags: unity, animation, maya, fbx

I have a grass made by PaintEffects tool (1) and "animated" by adding turbulence (2) and then baked with Maya 2012.

[image]

And in Maya everything looks perfect - animation works. Problem is, when I'm importing that .fbx animation to Unity 2018, nothing happens. I can't either see this animation in Preview, I can see only the "model" itself. I read on the internet that's maybe because I set wrong animation, or rig option in Unity, but I tried every one of them. Is there something I missed, either in Maya, or Unity? Maybe I have too old version of Maya?

Also, I was trying to save that animation into separate files, or with extensions like .ma, .mb... Nothing works either.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Unity 2018 HAS TO work only with newer versions of Maya. I installed update for it and by the option "Send to Unity" my animation suddenly works.

I think that the main issue lays upon the .fbx importer version. It should be as new as possible.